# Waiting for two Observables and execute a method which returns an Observable

Tags: rx-java

I have two `Observables<T>` named `obsOne` and `obsTwo` whose results I want to combine and then call a method which returns an `Observable<R>`. I attempted to do

```
Observables.zip(obsOne, obsTwo, (r1, r2) -> myMethodReturningObservableR(r1, r2));
```

but I ended up with an instance of `Observable<Observable<R>>`, which is not what I need. After skimming through the documentation I found `switchOnNext`, and now I am using

```
Observables.switchOnNext(Observables.zip(obs1, obs2, (r1, r2) -> myMethodReturningObservableR(r1, r2));
```

but this somehow doesn't feel right. I'd like to ask two questions:

1. Is this usage of `switchOnNext(zip(...))` acceptable in "conceptual" and performance terms? (All three observers emit exactly one value or an error.)
2. Is there a nicer syntax or an operator that shorthands `switchOnNext(zip(...))` (or some other operator that is equivalent in this scenario)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just flatten the observable to get `Observable<R>`:

```
Observables
    .zip(obsOne, obsTwo, (r1, r2) -> myMethodReturningObservableR(r1, r2))
    .flatMap(o -> o);
```